# Cached value while retrieving template in UDM_DISPUTE

Tags: abap, netweaver

I'm trying to retrieve templates in Dispute Management (TCODE: `UDM_DISPUTE`).

The first time, it doesn't retrieve them because the document is still initial and it has to create a connection. Somewhere along the line, it gets the ID of the template, however another ID is getting **cached** somewhere and it is the wrong value. I can't find out how to clear or disable it. Any ideas?

The templates are stored in transaction `SRMREGEDITC` --> `S_AREA_CMG` --> `SCMG_SP_DOCUMENT_TEMP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue some time ago. Make sure your template profile is specific for your element type (**UDM_SPS_DOCUMENT_TEMP**). If there is some sort of cross-over, you might create document from a template that is from a different type and this can cause errors.

Hope this helps.